# XPath to return default value if node not present

Tags: xpath

Say I have a pair of XML documents

```
<Foo>
    <Bar/>
    <Baz>mystring</Baz>
</Foo>
```

and

```
<Foo>
    <Bar/>
</Foo>
```

I want an XPath (Version 1.0 only) that returns "mystring" for the first document and "not-found" for the second. I tried

```
(string('not-found') | //Baz)[last()]
```

but the left hand side of the union isn't a node-set

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In XPath 1.0, use:

```
concat(/Foo/Baz,
       substring('not-found', 1 div not(/Foo/Baz)))
```

If you want to handle the posible empty `Baz` element, use:

```
concat(/Foo/Baz,
       substring('not-found', 1 div not(/Foo/Baz[node()])))
```

With this input:

```
<Foo>
    <Baz/>
</Foo>
```

Result: `not-found` string data type.

Comment: That's a really unintuitive XPath, and when my real world XPath to the node is substituted it is a really ugly XPath too. But got to hand it to you, it's really clever.

Comment: @Paul McKenzie: Thanks, you are wellcome. But this is not mine, this is Oliver Becker's method. There are a lot of answer here in SO using it.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious to most, but the `div` is divide, not an html div tag. Just putting that out there. :)

Comment: This doesn't work, it gives "expected type 'nodeset', got 'string'"

Comment: @Worse_Username, I had to use `concat(@wiki,substring(@name, 1 div number(not(@wiki))))`. Put the `number()` function in there.

Answer (score 18):

Special case:
If you want to get 0 if numeric node is missing or empty, use `sum(/Foo/Baz)` function

Answer (score 9):

**@Alejandro provided the best XPath 1.0 answer, which has been known for years, since [first used by Jeni Tennison](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200102/msg00191.html) almost ten years ago**.

The only problem with this expression is its shiny elegance, which makes it difficult to understand by not only novice programmers.

**In a hosted XPath 1.0 (and every XPath is hosted!) one can use more understandable expressions**:

```
string((/Foo/Baz | $vDefaults[not(/Foo/Baz/text())]/Foo/Baz)[last())
```

Here the variable `$vDefaults` is a separate document that has the same structure as the primary XML document, and whose text nodes contain default values.

**Or, if XSLT is the hosting language, one can use the `document()` function**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output  method="text"/>

 <my:defaults>
    <Foo>
        <Bar/>
        <Baz>not-found</Baz>
  </Foo>
 </my:defaults>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(/Foo/Baz,
           document('')[not(current()/Foo/Baz/text())]
                                        /*/my:defaults/Foo/Baz
           )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Or, not using `concat()`**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output  method="text"/>

 <my:defaults>
    <Foo>
        <Bar/>
        <Baz>not-found</Baz>
  </Foo>
 </my:defaults>

 <xsl:variable name="vDefaults" select="document('')/*/my:defaults"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "(/Foo/Baz 
       | $vDefaults/Foo/Baz[not(current()/Foo/Baz/text())]
       )
        [last()]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Doesn't output anything for me.

Comment: @Worse_Username, you need to use a compliant XSLT 1.0 processor -- which you (missed to specify anything?!?) aren't using.

Answer (score 5):

```
/Foo/(Baz/string(), 'not-found')[1]
```

Comment: this works in version 2 of XPath. In version 1.0 I get Unexpected token - ", 'not-found')[1]".  Unfortunately I need an XPath 1.0 solution. I will edit the question to reflect this

Comment: To yield the default value for a node with empty text content as well, use: /Foo/(Baz/text(), 'not-found')[1]

Answer (score 3):

If you are okay with printing an empty string instead of 'not-found' message then use:

```
/Foo/concat(Baz/text(), '')
```

Later, you can replace the empty strings with 'not-found'.