# How can I set a value to an empty xml field in logstash

Tags: xml, xpath, logstash

I get some xml messages with logstash that I parse in order to get relevant info

```
if ([message] =~ /^</) {
      xml {
        source => "message"
        store_xml => false
        xpath => [
          "name(/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/APIOS_EXPORT/*[not(self::METADATA)])","MESSAGE_TYPE",              
        ]
        target => "xml"
      }
      if ([MESSAGE_TYPE] == "") {
        mutate {
          update => { "MESSAGE_TYPE" => "EDITO" }
        }
      }
    }
```

My goal is to get all MESSAGE_TYPE and if it's empty, to set it to EDITO.
Right now I can see empty message in kibana with (MESSAGE_TYPE.raw:"") but I don't see any EDITO MESSAGE_TYPE.

I have some MESSAGE_TYPE : TEXTS, MATERIALS, PHOTOS but no EDITO (only empty messages)

[image: kibana fiels]

So to sum it up, *Empty string* should be EDITO

I already read some doc (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-replace https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/logstash-users/mKJVO6yAmSc/on9mLRtLgTYJ) but still no luck

Comment: I also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489976/xpath-to-return-default-value-if-node-not-present but I'm not sure how to deal with it

Comment: Try with something that should not fait ```if [MESSAGE_TYPE] {
        if ([MESSAGE_TYPE] == "") {
          mutate {
            update => { "MESSAGE_TYPE" => "EDITO" }
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        mutate {
          add_field => { "MESSAGE_TYPE" => "EDITO" }
        }
      }
``` but still empty instead of EDITO

Comment: Maybe the trick is to use the 'alter' plugin (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-alter.html) ```  alter {
        condrewrite => [
          "MESSAGE_TYPE","","EDITO"
        ]
      }
 ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I have it :)
I had to install a logstash plugin (alter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-alter.html)
And the here the logstash conf

```
xml {
        add_field => { "genre" => "xml"}
        source => "message"
        store_xml => false
        xpath => [
          "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/IDENT/NO_EMIARTE/text()", "NO_EMIARTE",
          "/APISTAT_EVENT/IDENT/NO_EMIARTE/text()", "NO_EMIARTE",
          "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/APIOS_EXPORT/METADATA/VECTORS/VECTOR","VECTORS",
          "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/APIOS_EXPORT/METADATA/VECTORS/VECTOR/@NAME","VECTOR_NAME",
          "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/INFO_EVENT/SENDER/text()","SENDER",
          "/APISTAT_EVENT/INFO_EVENT/SENDER/text()","SENDER",
          "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/APIOS_EXPORT/METADATA/VECTORS/VECTOR/@ONLINE","ON_LINE",
          "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/APIOS_EXPORT/METADATA/VECTORS/VECTOR/@OFFLINE","OFF_LINE",
          "name(/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/APIOS_EXPORT/*[not(self::METADATA)])","MESSAGE_TYPE",
          "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/APIOS_EXPORT/METADATA/CODE_OFFRE_WEB/text()","OFFRE_WEB"
        ]
        target => "xml"
      }
      alter {
        condrewrite => [
          "MESSAGE_TYPE","","EDITO"
        ]
      }
```

Now I have my EDITO message correctly

[image: Kibana / discover tab with EDITO message]

This plugin will be part of logstash core (*The functionality provided by this plugin is likely to be merged into the mutate filter in future versions.*)