# XPATH get default value when node is empty or not present

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have 3 types of data

```
<results>
   <place>
      <key>place</key>
      <value>1</value>
   </place>
</results>
```

OR

```
<results>
   <place>
      <key>place</key> // notice the missing value
   </place>
</results>
```

OR

```
<results>
</results>
```

So my sample data will be like

```
<event>
    <results>
        <place>
            <key>place</key>
            <value>1</value>
        </place>
        <some additional data here>
    </results>
</event>
<event>
    <results>
        <place>
            <key>place</key>
        </place>
        <some additional data here>
    </results>
</event>
<event>
    <results>
        <some additional data here>
    </results>
</event>
```

I need an XPath expression that can give me a default value when `<value>` of `<place>` is present, null or missing. `<place>` can be missing as well in some cases as mentioned in my third sample data.

Output that I expect here is `1, <default-value>, <default-value>`.

XPATH 2.0 solution will work as well. I have tried scourging stackoverflow and google but couldnt find anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath to return default value if node not present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489976/xpath-to-return-default-value-if-node-not-present)

Comment: I have tried that but somehow that doesnt work for me.

Comment: Have you tried in this way: `concat(//place/value, substring('not-found', 1 div not(//place/value[node()])))` ?

Comment: i have tried following `{xpath::/events/event/results//concat((place|rank)/value,
       substring('not-found', 1 div not((place|rank)/value)))}`  and `{xpath::/events/event/results//concat((place|rank)/value,
       substring('not-found', 1 div not((place|rank)/value[node()])))}` and `{xpath::concat(//events/event/results//(place|rank)/value,
       substring('not-found', 1 div not(//events/event/results//(place|rank)/value)))}` and `{xpath::concat(//events/event/results//(place|rank)/value,
       substring('not-found', 1 div not(//events/event/results//(place|rank)/value[node()])))}`

Comment: `<events>` is the top level parent and `<place>` and `<rank>` are used interchangeably.

Comment: no, in xpath 1.0 it will not work. You are right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it finally after a lot of trial and error.

```
{xpath::/events/event/(results//(place|rank)/value/string(), '')[1]}
```

the trick was to go one level up i.e. `<results>` in my case and then use the (if value present, `default-value`) XPATH notation.

Earlier, I was trying this unsuccessfully.

```
{xpath::/events/event/results//((place|rank)/value/string(), '')[1]}
```

Comment: user3440050: What you provide as a solution is not a syntactically correct XPath expression -- you probably rely on a specific API of a particular programming language. See a pure XPath 2.0 solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
//results/concat(place/value, for $r in . return 'default-value'[not($r/place/value)])
```

XSLT - based verification:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
 "//results/concat(place/value, for $r in . return 'default-value'[not($r/place/value)])"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on the provided (and completed) XML document:

```
<t>
    <event>
        <results>
            <place>
                <key>place</key>
                <value>1</value>
            </place>
            <x/>
        </results>
    </event>
    <event>
        <results>
            <place>
                <key>place</key>
            </place>
            <y/>
        </results>
    </event>
    <event>
        <results>
            <z/>
        </results>
    </event>
</t>
```

the XPath expression is evaluated and its results are copied to the output:

```
1 default-value default-value
```